# SOLR SurroundQueryParser \ can it come with NOT

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

Is it possible to use Surround Query in a complex query
for example

(query1) - (surround query2)
or
(surround query2) - (query1)

for example:
Fetch dosuments that contains Text2 after Text1, without docs with Text3

```
{!surround}SomeField:30w(Text1*,Text2*) -SomeField:Text3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `NOT` operator.

```
{!surround}SomeField:30w(Text1*,Text2*) NOT(SomeField:Text3)
```

See also: [Solr's SurroundQueryParser documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SurroundQueryParser)

Comment: Working!! however the other direction gets an exception (SomeField:Text3) NOT {!surround}SomeField:30w(Text1*,Text2*) - is that doable?